# SQL get rank of ordered data

Tags: sql

I have a data set that looks like this (ordered by date):

| date | value | first_id | second_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 75 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-05 | 101 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-06 | 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-07 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-08 | 14 | 1 | 2 |

I need to get an aggregation when values are the same for the same first_id and second_id in a sequence, lets say max(value), so I can get:

| max_value | first_id | second_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 101 | 2 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 | 2 |

If you do max(value) and group by, same first_id and second_id combinations will give just one row (regardless of date ordering).
I was thinking to add RANK when one of ids changes, e.g:

| date | value | first_id | second_id | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 15 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 75 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2020-01-05 | 101 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2020-01-06 | 12 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2020-01-07 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2020-01-08 | 14 | 1 | 2 | 5 |

But I don't know how to get that rank as well since same id combinations are considered together.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define the groups and then aggregate.  You can see the groups if you run this query:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_date = prev_date2 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
             lag(date) over (partition by first_id, second_id order by date) as prev_date2
      from t
     ) t;
```

The logic is saying that a new group starts when the previous date does not have the same values of the two id columns.

Then the aggregation is:

```
with grps as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_date = prev_date2 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
                   lag(date) over (partition by first_id, second_id order by date) as prev_date2
            from t
           ) t
      )
select first_id, second_id, max(value), min(date), max(date)
from grps
group by grp
```